# Cannot freeze the table header while scrolling the rows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some Gap  remains between Table Top and Table Header only when table loads and scrolled down to the last row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426185/some-gap-remains-between-table-top-and-table-header-only-when-table-loads-and-sc)

I am using Xcode.

```
 self.mytable.tableheaderview=label;
```

By this code I can get the header but I can not freeze it...plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is create a `UIViewController` which is a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, and have a `UILabel` at the top of the `UIViewController`'s **nib**, and a `UITableView` underneath the `UILabel`. This will have the effect of having the `UILabel` staying put in its position, with the `UITableView` still able to scroll like normal. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thank You very much, actually i have thought it before, but went for some programatical table rows solutions , again thanks very much..

Answer (score 2):

This question sounds a like one I just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426185/some-gap-remains-between-table-top-and-table-header-only-when-table-loads-and-sc/7426455#7426455). All you should have to do is set `yourTable.bounces = NO;` in your viewDidLoad function. Either that or uncheck the "Bounces" option in the NIB if you used Interface Builder to layout your table.

Comment: I just noticed you were the one who posted the other question I answered. Did that not take care of the problem?

Comment: Actually I have done on that way also but at that time only one problem remains..I have mentined that there is a gap remains bewween header view and Table top..How to resolve it??if u hv any idea..otherwise everything goes fine....check my edit where u hv answered

Comment: I went ahead and posted a fix for the problem you elaborated on in your other post.

Comment: I am setting `tableview.bounces = NO;` but still header is not fixed at top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by freezing? If what you think is to stop it from scrolling while scrolling the rows of the table, I don't think its possible. See the table header is part of the table view and is designed to scroll along with the rows. If you just want a header that is static, dont make it a table header. Just add a view or label separately and place it above the table view. The table view will then scroll below that.