# Can i make a table's tableHeaderView position fixed as I scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view and have attached to its tableHeaderView a UISegmentedControl. How can I make the tableHeaderView fixed so that i can always view the UISegmentedControl in the same position even when i am scrolling the table view?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426849/can-not-freez-the-table-header-while-scrolling-the-rows/7427117#7427117

Comment: I used a toolbar on the viewcontroller and put whatever objects there... in one of my projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tableView:ViewForHeaderInSection:` is your option to achieve your task. In plain table this will somehow looks like Address Book app with first char of name in section, but you will have your segmented control

Comment: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will allow the UITableViewDelegate to return custom views for section headers, but these views *will scroll* when the rest of the table scrolls.

Comment: Yes, I see them scrolling with the top of their respective sections in the Contacts app (and sticking to the top *only* when rows from that section are occupying the top of the table view). So I guess the question is whether Badescu requires a per-section fixed header or a single fixed header for the whole table. Based on the attempts to use a tableHeaderView, I'd assumed the latter. (Of course, the two are almost equivalent for a table with only 1 section...)

Comment: I understand what Basescu don't need sections at all, so he can use this approach for plain table an single section for whole rows in table.

Comment: Doesn't stay fixed, scrolling down moves the header down.

Comment: @indiekiduk I think Mark's response will be useful for you (his response next one in a row).

Comment: `tableView:ViewForHeaderInSection:` applies to sections not the whole tableview which is what `tableHeaderView` applies to.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest placing the UISegmentedControl in a separate view on top of the UITableView rather than in the tableHeaderView. You might also want to set `yourTable.bounces = NO;` in order to keep the header view from bouncing when you get to the top of the table.

Answer (score 1):

First lower the tableview's frame(make space on top of tableview).  Then during scrollViewDidscroll, fix the tableviewheader, properly, so it doesn't scroll with it.

Thats the summary of it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @mskw's answer:

You can use the UITableViewController (keep the niceties such as UIRefreshControl support and keyboard avoidance). You just have to embed your toolbar in a plain view and place that in your tableHeaderView. Then implement this scroll view delegate method to lock.

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect rect = self.toolbarContainerView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MIN(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top);
    self.toolbarContainerView.frame = rect;
}
```

Note that if you also use section headers you will have to send those views behind your tableHeaderView otherwise they will float over the tableHeaderView.