# iPhone: How to add a UILabel on top of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my Universal IOS4 app, I have a UITableview in my xib and I control it with my UITableViewController. As you know tableview by default covers all the area in window left from the navigation bar on top and the toolbar at the bottom.

What I want is to  add another UIComponent(probably a big UILabel) just under the navigation bar and place the scrollable tableview just under that UILabel, so UIlabel is not scrollable but only the table is

How can I do and control that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want a customized tableview header. I would explore your options for headers and see what you come up with.

Comment: Your other option is to create your own view and add the tableview to it directly, giving you control over the tableview dimensions. Then you can leave yourself room at the top for your label.

Comment: @Bill Brasky can u explain what u mean by creating my own view?

Comment: If you create a new view controller classed as UITableViewController, it creates all the tableview stuff for you, but restricts your ability to resize the tableview. If you create just a normal view controller and add your own tableview to it, you can leave yourself room at the top for your label. But you need to manually link your tableview datasource and outlets to the new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to go with using UITableViewCOntroller at all. If you use UITableVIewCOntroller to ease the way you use Delegates and Data Sources, then you will have to face this kind of Customization problems.

You will have below problems if you UITableViewController:

1. can not set the background to a custom UIImage. You can only set the UITableView’s BG property. If you use a Custom VC and add a UITableView to it. you can entirely customize what to keep on top of the View, widtt and height of your table view.
2. You can not have a static Header view in your  View at all. Because if you use UITableVC, you can only have the default header that you can create using Table View's data source methods. But if you use a customized VC and add a TableView to it, you can add your own customized header or controls as a header.

only advantage you will have if you use a UITableViewController is that if you have UITextFields in your Table View, UITableViewCOntroller will automatically scroll the hidden text field to above the Keypad if you start editing one.

I would not suggest you to add anything to UIWIndow, as only the first added view to window will get the rotation events

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

Never mind:  I think this will scroll with the table.

You can set the section header to the view below.  This may work if you only have one section.  Best solution would be to change to a UIViewController.

Programmatically add a header to the table

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)] autorelease];
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,30)] autorelease];
label.text = "Hello";
[view addSubview:label];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple idea is to have another UIViewController (let's call this a_viewController) and set the tableview (let's call it a_tableView) and the label (samewise, a_label) as its subviews.

```
[a_viewController.view addSubview:a_tableView]
[a_viewController.view addSubview:a_label];
```

TableView header may not work in case you want the label to stay as you scroll.

But if you have only one section in your tableview, section header may become a handy option.

[Can i make a table's tableHeaderView position fixed as I scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433681/can-i-make-a-tables-tableheaderview-position-fixed-as-i-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is you can add on `UIWindow`. But make sure you handle it properly while navigating views... Following is the way...

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myView];
```

Create your `UILabel` instance (myView) and add it as subview in `UIWindow`...