# View table size and positioning won't change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a xib tableview controller and i can't get the size of the table view to shrink so that i may add additional things before the view(I would like to add some buttons). I try changing the frame in `viewdidload` and `viewwillappear` but nothing seams so work. I am using

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200);
```

but the view remains in place(just under the navigation bar). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a nib file? If so, positioning issues like this are *easily* solved.

Comment: i can't modify the X or Y position in the interface builder, it's strange!

Comment: Is your View Controller a `UIViewController`, or a `UITableViewController`? If its the latter, change it to the former.

Comment: what do you mean change it to the latter? How do i do so?

Comment: Read my earlier post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426849/can-not-freez-the-table-header-while-scrolling-the-rows/7427117#7427117

Comment: MSgambel's solution is the one you are looking for. You can not modify the frame if your View Controller is a UITableViewController!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you resize in the `xib` tableView itself? What's preventing you to do that?

**EDIT**: Why cant you change the height in `xib` or `x` and `y` coordinates? Attaches image should help you do this easily in IB - (make sure to select your `tableView` and open the right hand sidebar to get this menu. Once right sidebar opens goto - Size Inspector & here you can do this.

[image]

Comment: in the IB I can't modify the x and y position and when i resize the height, the resize is useless because when i run the program i still get the same height

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i realized that my tableView was inside another TableView with its own x and y (so probably i was not able to change it). So you have to make sure that your TableView is a subview of your view or is your main view

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIViewController, drag and drop a UITableView in it, resize as per your wish and there you've got what you were looking for.