# Possible to add a "sticky" header to a grouped table view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is there a natural way to add a header for a grouped table view section that scrolls along with the user? The same as the way section headers can scroll in a normal table view?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this post: [Cannot freeze the table header while scrolling the rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426849/can-not-freez-the-table-header-while-scrolling-the-rows/7427117#7427117)

Personally, I think the best way to handle this would be to go with normal table view and customize the `UITableViewCells` and headers to be exactly what you want.